# Facebook Share Button with Facebook App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have made quiz website and in order to get the score of the quiz, the user must click the Facebook share button. The button then shares the results of the quiz and a blurb getting their friends to play the quiz too. It's all working well, except for one thing:

If the person is using a mobile device and they click share it loads up a new browser tab. This is bad because most people use the Facebook app and not a browser. So if they click share on my website, they will go to the Facebook login page before they can share it. I'm guessing most people don't bother.

How to get the 'share' to go to the app which they will almost always be logged into and not open a new tab on the browser? Whilst at the same time not affecting the functionality of the share button on a desktop browser or a mobile device without the app installed? I've looked all though Facebook Developers and I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported. The root of the problem here is, that you can't check if a specific app is installed or not using the browser. This is a good for privacy and security reasons.

So as of now, no, you can't do this, there is no setting or something that would make the Share Button work in that fashion on a mobile client.